# VBA Problem with large data in double looped array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm having problems with this and there must be some better way of doing it, the code works but it's just very slow. Array1 is 80 000 rows and Array2 has 600 000 rows which is a lot. Would much appreciate ideas for doing this faster. :)

Array1 has unique rows and searches through Array2 to find matching rows, on match summing values and add them to Array1. Basically summing the 600 000 rows with the correct 80 000 unique rows.

```
For i = 0 To UBound(Array1, 2)
    For ii = 0 To UBound(Array2, 2)
        If Array1(0, i) = Array2(27, ii) And Array1(2, i) = Array2(20, ii) Then
            Array1(1, i) = Array2(21, ii)
            Array1(3, i) = Array2(25, ii)
            Array1(4, i) = Array1(4, i) + Array2(24, ii)
        End If
    Next ii
Next i
```

edit: Thanks BigBen and VBasic for the ideas, much appreciated. So to elaborate on how I end up with these 2 arrays, possibly I have a convoluted process. So: 1) I have a semicolon separated txt file with 600 000 rows. The rows are not unique. 2) I read the file with a CreateObject and add the data through ObjFile.readall to an array. 3) Line by line I split it to a 2d array, split on semicolon. 4) I loop through the 2d array and add unique values to a collection. 5) I move the unique values from the collection to Array1. Everything up to this point is fast. 6) The loop above is the last step.

edit2: This is the rest of the code leading up to the above. It's fast enough to work.

```
'Adds rows from TXT to array
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(txtfile, 1)
strIn = objFile.readall
ArrayLines = Split(strIn, vbNewLine)
objFile.Close
Set objFile = Nothing

'Splits data on semicolon to Array1
Dim Month As String: Month = Format(Date, "mm")
ReDim Array1(0 To 27, 0 To TxtNumberOfRows)
For i = 0 To UBound(ArrayLines)
    splitLine = Split(ArrayLines(i), ";")
    For ii = 0 To UBound(splitLine)
        Array1(ii, i) = splitLine(ii)
    Next ii
    Array1(23, i) = Array1(14, i) / 10000
    Array1(24, i) = Array1(17, i) / 100
    Array1(25, i) = "F" & Month - 1
    For iii = 0 To UBound(ArrayTranslate, 2)
        If ArrayTranslate(0, iii) & "" = Array1(19, i) & "" Then
            Array1(26, i) = ArrayTranslate(3, iii)
        End If
    Next iii
    Array1(27, i) = Array1(8, i) & Array1(26, i) & ""
Next i

'Loops through Array1 to fins unique values
On Error Resume Next
Dim UniqueColl As New Collection
For i = 0 To UBound(Array1, 2)
    UniqueColl.Add (Array1(27, i) & "¤" & Array1(20, i)), CStr(Array1(27, i) & "¤" & Array1(20, i))
Next i
On Error GoTo 0

'Move data from collection to Array2
Dim Splitted
ReDim Array2(0 To 4, 0 To UniqueColl.Count)
For i = 1 To UniqueColl.Count
    Splitted = Split(UniqueColl(i), "¤")
    Array2(0, i - 1) = Splittad(0)
    Array2(2, i - 1) = Splittad(1)
Next i
```

Comment: One option might be to loop Array2 and store its unique values (combination of column 27 and 20) and their sum in a `Scripting.Dictionary`. Then loop through Array1 and read the corresponding sums from the dictionary. Should be fewer than the current 48 billion iterations. Or the reverse - store unique values from Array1 in a dictionary, then read in the corresponding values from Array2 and keep track of the sum.

Comment: Could you share the code of how you put the data into the arrays? It is usually done in one go e.g. `Array1 = rg1.Value`, which produces a 2D one-based array. So how come you start looping with `0`?

Comment: Thanks BigBen and VBasic for the ideas, much appreciated. So to elaborate on how I end up with these 2 arrays, possibly I have a convoluted process. So: 1) I have a semicolon separated txt file with 600 000 rows. The rows are not unique. 2) I read the file with a CreateObject and add the data through ObjFile.readall to an array. 3) Line by line I split it to a 2d array, split on semicolon. 4) I loop through the 2d array and add unique values to a collection. 5) I move the unique values from the collection to Array1. Everything up to this point is fast. 6) The loop above is the last step.

Comment: Addes more code leading up to the loop.

Comment: Would a dictionary work? Not sure about your application but if you're searching for matching things between two lists, comparing two hash tables might be way quicker. I worked out a similar problem with large amounts of text data in C++ a couple years ago and the hash tables improved performance stupidly.  Or, it sounds like you could use a join in power query.